# Oracle PL/SQL: What's missing in this trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to Triggers and PL/SQL in general. FOr testing purpose I'm using slely the Oracle Database Express Edition with its own Command Line.

The script supposed to create a trigger looks like follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SESSION_LOGIN_HANDLER 
AFTER UPDATE OF LOGGED_IN ON BENUTZERKONTO 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN 

    if (:OLD.LOGGED_IN == 1)
    if (:NEW.LOGGED_IN == 0)
    {
        UPDATE SESSION_LOGGING AS current_session SET DAUER = (sysdate-ZEITSTEMPEL) WHERE DAUER IS NULL AND SECURE_IDENTIFIER = :NEW.SECURE_IDENTIFIER;
    }
END; 

commit;
```

And I call it with @C:/SQL.../DB_TRIGGER.trg; in the command line.
Yet just after calling it, the command line seems just to count the line number with each time I press .
It seems like it somehow waits for another line or anything, but I don't know what ><
There's also no failure message or anything.
I even commented out the entire code between "BEGIN" and "END" with no difference!

Could someone help this beginner? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag since this is about Oracle

Comment: I bet this is one of those cases where you need a `/` on a line by itself after the `END;` to tell PL/SQL that the command is really done.

Comment: Add a slash on the line after the trigger end to submit the buffer to the server. Also get rid of the `if` and put add condition to `where` clause on the update statement.

Comment: Get rid of the `commit` and add the slash as others have suggested. DDL such as this will automatically commit. Also, `if` requires both a `then` and `end if` (no braces and parentheses are not necessary for the condition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's no Oracle syntax, it must be like this:

```
if (:OLD.LOGGED_IN = 1) then
  if (:NEW.LOGGED_IN = 0) then   
     UPDATE SESSION_LOGGING AS current_session SET DAUER = (sysdate-ZEITSTEMPEL) 
     WHERE DAUER IS NULL AND SECURE_IDENTIFIER = :NEW.SECURE_IDENTIFIER;
  end if;
end if;
```

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I got this myself later again... it was just a while ago since I had to use PL/SQL the last time...